# WPF Simple custom shape

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I created a simple custom shape class and two properties "ActiveColor" (Type: Color) and "Active" (Type: bool). when I set Active to true, the shape should change the color defined in ActiveColor....and the color is still transparent....

follow my custom class:

```
public class Ellipse2 : Shape
{


    public bool Active
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ActiveProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Active.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Active", typeof(bool), typeof(Ellipse2), new UIPropertyMetadata(ActiveChanged));



    public Color ActiveColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ActiveColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ActiveColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveColor", typeof(Color), typeof(Ellipse2), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent));



    EllipseGeometry ellipse;

    private static void ActiveChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var shape = d as Ellipse2;
        var color = shape.Active ? shape.ActiveColor : Colors.Transparent;
        shape.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }


    public Ellipse2()
    {
        ellipse = new EllipseGeometry();
        this.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
        this.StrokeThickness = 1;
    }
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
           TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform(ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2);
            ellipse.Transform = t;
            ellipse.RadiusX = this.ActualWidth / 2;
            ellipse.RadiusY = this.ActualHeight / 2;
            return ellipse;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML usage:

```
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <controls:Ellipse2 ActiveColor="Red" Height="{StaticResource height}" Width="{StaticResource width}" Active="False" />
                                    <controls:Ellipse2 ActiveColor="Blue" Height="{StaticResource height}" Width="{StaticResource width}"  Active="False" />
                                    <controls:Ellipse2 ActiveColor="Yellow" Height="{StaticResource height}" Width="{StaticResource width}" Active="True"  />
                                    <controls:Ellipse2 ActiveColor="Orange" Height="{StaticResource height}" Width="{StaticResource width}" Active="True"  />
                                    <controls:Ellipse2 ActiveColor="Black" Height="{StaticResource height}" Width="{StaticResource width}" Active="True"  />
                                    <controls:Ellipse2 ActiveColor="Pink" Height="{StaticResource height}" Width="{StaticResource width}" Active="False"  />
                                    <controls:Ellipse2 ActiveColor="Green" Height="{StaticResource height}" Width="{StaticResource width}" Active="False"  />
                                </StackPanel>
```

When Active property changes, i would like to fill the ellipse with color defined in ActiveColor, when Active is set to TRUE. What´s wrong with my code?

tks.

Comment: You should also update the fill of your ellipse whenever *ActiveColor* changes. It could very well be in your case that the XAML sets the *Active* property first before setting the *ActiveColor* property - so the *Active* callback still works with the *ActiveColor* property being transparent. Aside from this, debug your code, especially *ActiveChanged*, to see what the actual current property values are when this method is being executed...

Comment: changing the order to "<controls:Ellipse2 Active="True" ActiveColor="Purple" didin´t work,

Comment: Registering the same callback method to ActiveColor property work perfectly... thanks a lot.